# Load a table from another database in pyspark

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql, aws-glue, amazon-athena

I am currently working with AWS and PySpark. My tables are stored in S3 and queryable from Athena.

In my Glue jobs, I'm used to load my tables as:

```py
my_table_df = sparkSession.table("myTable")
```

However, this time, I want to access a table from another database, in the same data source (AwsDataCatalog). So I do something that works well:

```py
my_other_table_df = sparkSession.sql("SELECT * FROM anotherDatabase.myOtherTable")
```

I am just looking for a better way to write the same thing, without using a SQL query, in one line, just by specifying the database for this operation. Something that should looks like

```
sparkSession.database("anotherDatabase").table("myOtherTable")
```

Any suggestion would be welcome

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [DynamicFrameReader](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/dg/aws-glue-api-crawler-pyspark-extensions-dynamic-frame-reader.html#aws-glue-api-crawler-pyspark-extensions-dynamic-frame-reader-from_catalog) for that. This will return you a DynamicFrame. You can just call .toDF() on that DynamicFrame to transform it into a native Spark DataFrame though.

```
sc = SparkContext()
glue_context = GlueContext(sc)
spark = glue_context.spark_session
job = Job(glue_context)

data_source = glue_context.create_dynamic_frame.from_catalog(
            database="database",
            table_name="table_name"
).toDF()
```

Comment: almost perfect: `AttributeError: 'DynamicFrame' object has no attribute 'toDf'`

Comment: It is a function, not an attribute. I've updated the answer

Comment: This is what I've done. It doesn't work. `data_source.toDf()` -> ` no attribute 'toDf'`

Comment: It is an uppercase F in DF not lowercase.

Comment: I wanted to add that you can also specify the **catalogue**: with the argument `catalog_id="XXX"` in from_catalog function. XXX correspond to your account ID.